# Encrypt with RSACryptoServiceProvider and public key string on Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, rsa, public-key-encryption, windows-mobile-6.5

my Windows Mobile 6 application needs to send data to a php REST web service of a company.
that WS has a method that returns the public key to use to encrypt the username and password of the user of the mobile application.

They give me a sample code written in php which simply calls the WS to obtain the public key and then calls openssl_public_encrypt with, as public key parameter, the value returned by the web service's call. This is an excerpt

```
function CallAPI($url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data)); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

$public_key=CallAPI(, "https://***.***.***/index.php/rest/getPKey");
$json = json_encode(array("username"=>"********","psw"=>"*******"));
openssl_public_encrypt($json, $encrypted, $public_key);
```

From Windows Mobile point of view seems to be more complicated than this, also I am not really into RSA encryption.

the first thing I do is to call the WS to obtain the public key and I save it into a string. The following is the code I use to encrypt data.

```
ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes(data_string);
byte[] public_key = ByteConverter.GetBytes(public_key_string);
byte[] encryptedData;

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA_provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSAParameters key_info = RSA_provider.ExportParameters(false);

key_info.Modulus = public_key;

RSA_provider.ImportParameters(key_info);

encryptedData = RSA_provider.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
string encrypted_string = ByteConverter.GetString(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);

return encrypted_string;
```

If I try to send data to the web service it fails due to an authentication failure, also I noted that from php code that the encrypted string is always of 256 chars, while the .NET encrypted string has completely different length.

What I'm doing wrong?
I have seen a lot of questions on StackOverflow about working with .NET and RSA Encryption, but the features that are used are not contained in the Compact Framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert arbitrary binary bytes to an ASCII string? That is always wrong. Please post the sample PHP code or else how can anybody possibly know for sure what is the correct method.

Comment: I've added an excerpt of the php sample code. @GregS Probably I'm wrong, but a I need to send the encrypted data to a REST web service, hence I guess that I have to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved using BouncyCastle API for ecnryption/decryption on .NET side and sending data between Windows Mobile client and PHP server using UrlEncode and replacing all '+'s in the UrlEncoded string with a custom string known from both the client and the server, I decided for "####".